# Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate , live data plot , matplotlib, python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, live, updating

I am currently managing to show the updating live data with matplotlib, python.

But I see the error.

my code :

```
    plt.rcParams['animation.html'] = 'jshtml'
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    fig.show()

    i = 0
    plot_x , plot_y = [], []

    while True :

        ###some code to get live updating x_in_data###

        x_in_data = np.reshape(x_in, (1))

        print(x_in_data)


        plot_x.append(i)
        plot_y.append(x_in_data[0])
        ax.plot(plot_x, plot_y, color='b')
        fig.canvas.draw()

        ax.set_xlim(left=max(0, i-50), right= i+50)

        time.sleep(0.1)
        i += 1
```

I see this error message :

**Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate**

**Python runtime state: initialized**

**Current thread 0x00004fc4 (most recent call first):**

It plots actually a small graph window, but not working.

Every solution that i found on the internet is not working for my case.

I wonder if it is the problem how the value is updated :

The data value is actually updated with newline,

[-18.75235738]

[-19.02642986]

[-18.75235738]

[-19.02642986]

[-18.75235738]

[-19.02642986]

[-18.92591474]

[-18.75235738]

like this ,and it is **not** being updated by changing itself.

I would like to know if it is related with the updating method or not.

Or I would like to also know it there is an efficient way to plot the "new line updating value".

Answer (score 1):

Adding **fig.canvas.flush_events()** after ***fig.convas.draw()*** solves the issue.

```
# ==========Working sample of your code===========
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import numpy as np

plt.rcParams['animation.html'] = 'jshtml'
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.show()

i = 0
plot_x, plot_y = [], []

while True:
    ###some code to get live updating x_in_data###

    x_in_data = np.reshape(10, (1))

    print(x_in_data)

    plot_x.append(i)
    plot_y.append(x_in_data[0])
    ax.plot(plot_x, plot_y, color='b')
    fig.canvas.draw()

    ax.set_xlim(left=max(0, i - 50), right=i + 50)
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    i += 1
```

Referenced from: https://pythonguides.com/matplotlib-update-plot-in-loop/